# Is there complex analytic function without branch cuts but with two singularities $\pm 1$ and quickly converging Taylor series at $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find a variant of "step" function $f(x)$, which fulfils following (as being sort of step function):

1. $\lim_{x\to-1}f(x)=-1$ (on real axis only)
2. $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)=1$ (on real axis only)
3. All real derivatives of $f$ at $-1$ and $1$ tend to zero. (if this is true then $f(\pm1)$ is undefined, because otherwise it would be constant function, which contradicts previous points)

In addition I would like to extend it to complex numbers in nicest way possible:

4. $f$ is complex analytic on $\mathbb{C\backslash\{-1,1\}}$. So it does not have any branch cuts or singularities other than $\pm1$.

And it is easy to calculate $f$ via series:

5. $f$ has Tailor series at $0$ with radius of convergence $1$ (obviously excluding $x=\pm1$). This actually follows from 4.
6. Tailor series at $0$ converge quickly enough - coefficients tend to $0$.

Satisfying first 3 point is easy, but I cannot find function satisfying all points.

Function which satisfies 1-5 is:

$$f(x)=\text{erf }\frac{x\sqrt{6}}{(1-x^2)^2}$$

where $\text{erf } x$ is [Error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). It should have radius of convergence $1$ because only singularities are $\pm1$, however coefficients in Tailor series are growing, so it converges really slowly:

$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{6}{\pi}}\left(2x-\frac{54 x^5}{5}-\frac{100 x^7}{7}+50 x^9+\frac{11892 x^{11}}{55}+\frac{2558 x^{13}}{13}-\frac{165656 x^{15}}{175}-\frac{67770 x^{17}}{17}-\frac{729472 x^{19}}{133}+O\left(x^{21}\right)\right)$

Another failing example is function satisfies all points except 4 because it has branch cuts (due to $\tanh^{-1}x$):

$$f(x)=\text{erf }\tanh^{-1}\left(x \exp{\frac{x^2-x^4}{2}}\right)$$

Its series is:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left(2x+x^3-\frac{49 x^5}{60}-\frac{1703 x^7}{2520}-\frac{22447 x^9}{181440}+\frac{34223 x^{11}}{950400}+\frac{16697987 x^{13}}{148262400}+\frac{30493802539 x^{15}}{217945728000}+\frac{5920501869131 x^{17}}{59281238016000}+\frac{229301989511773 x^{19}}{4054836680294400}+O\left(x^{21}\right)\right)$$

**Question**. Is such function even possible? If yes, please provide an example, if not, some reason why it isn't.

Comment: The requirements contradict each other.  You want poles at ±1 and also that the limit to ±1 is finite.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts: I understand that only the limit on the real line must be finite, not the general complex limit. It might be that it is still contradictory, though

Comment: If the real limit is finite, then the complex limit is finite or does not exist as $\Bbb R\subset\Bbb C$.  If it's a pole, then the real limit is ∞ or −∞. Also, if the radius of convergence is 1, then it *must* have a singularity of some sort (pole, essential singularity, finite or logarithmic branch point) with $|x|=1$.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts: Yeah, you're right. You can't have a "nonreal" pole. Thanks. (BTW Emacs drives me nuts, too)

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Sorry, I mixed terms. I meant just singularities (any kind), like in my function examples. I edited my question.

Comment: Note that 4 always implies 5 since Taylor series have singularities on the boundary disc of convergence; radius of convergence one doesn't mean bounded coefficients (one can have polynomial coefficients or even subexponential ones like $e^{\sqrt n}$ say)

Comment: @Conrad It seems that series is converging, but so slowly, that it is impossible to use it for calculation. I guess I need faster converging one. I will edit question when I am back home.

Comment: why don't you look at an asymptotic expansion for it if you need it for calculation as those tend to converge fast (any reasonable book on such have all the stuff you want to know about Erf and asymptotic expansions) - it may or may not work, but that's the first thing I would think about when I want to improve the speed of convergence of a Taylor series, namely find a much faster "convergent" (of course by "convergent" here I mean that the difference is small after only a few terms as asymptotic series diverge when you take many terms)  asymptotic series that represents the same function

Comment: How is this related to the Heaviside step function $\theta(x)$? Why are you requiring a branch point or singularity at $x=\pm 1$? There are real analytic representations of the Heaviside step function and the Dirac delta function $\delta(x)$, but there are no complex analytic representations of these two functions.

Comment: @StevenClark It is not related. It just looks similar to smoothstep function. That's why I said variant of "step" function in quotes. Such function doesn't exist without singularities, as described in point 3. If we look at it on real line, then there will be 2 removable singularities, so we can patch them. But it is easier to think about such function if there are singularities, because they still affect Taylor series.